# Multivariate mutual independence test

Tags: probability

I have a series of observations $\{X_i,Y_i,Z_i\}$ for random variable $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Now I want to test if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are mutual independent, can anyone help me?

Some pairwise independence tests like this one http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/indepTestFiles/indep.htm are available, but I haven't found such tests for multivariate mutual independence yet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $k$ random variables are mutually independent if $\displaystyle P\left( \cap_i R_i \right) = \Pi_i P(R_i)$

Comment: The issue here is the distribution of random variables X, Y and Z is unknown, only empirical sample pairs (X_i,Y_i, Z_i) can be observed

Answer (score 2):

For discrete variables, [Pearson's chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test#Test_of_independence) generalizes.  Estimate the probabilities in the 3D cells by multiplying the marginal probabilities (which is correct, given the assumption of independence).  The degrees of freedom are therefore $(k-1)(m-1)(n-1)$ when the variables have $k$, $m$, and $n$ distinct categories.

For normally distributed variables, use tests of correlation with adjustments for multiple comparisons.  (These are all approximate.)

For other variables, you can bin the values into classes defined *a priori* and apply a chi-squared test.  This is successful when it rejects the null hypothesis of independence; it is not so successful otherwise, because some power is lost in the binning.

Comment: Is there independence test specially for continuous multivariates?

Comment: @sino Not in general (that I know of).  There may be some generic independence tests based on [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28statistics%29), but the example of the multinormal distribution shows that you can expect to obtain more powerful tests by exploiting assumptions about the marginal distributions.